# Rails—how to see whether an email was sent in the past week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I'm sending an email to inactive users, saying "please sign in within 7 days or your account will be deactivated".

I have a service that will fetch all inactive users and send the email, but I run this daily, and I only want to email each user once, not every day.

```
class DeactivateOldEmailsService
  def run
    to_deactivate = User.havent_signed_in_for_n_days(97)
    to_deactivate.each { |user| user.update(active: false) }

    to_warn = User.havent_signed_in_for_n_days(90)
    to_warn.each do |user|
      messages_for_user_per_employer = InactiveEmailsMailer.account_will_expire(user).deliver_later
    end
  end
end
```

How can I check whether a user has been sent an email already?

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to check whether an user has been sent a notice email, if you did not save the time the email was sent in the database. There might be still some data in log file, but any sending job are quickly deleted from queue as soon as that email was sent successfully.

From your piece of source code, I guess you might have something like "last_signed_in" in your users table. You can just do it simple and send emails to users if they haven't signed in for exactly 90 days, something like:

```
to_warn.each do |user|
  if user.last_signed_in === 90.days.from_now
    messages_for_user_per_employer = InactiveEmailsMailer.account_will_expire(user).deliver_later
  end
end
```

Or you can create a new column `notice_deactivation_email_sent_at` in users table to check whether an user has received the notice email or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually facing something very similar:
Send weekly emails to user (who subscribed to changes that occurred since last sent), this Job is run every day and I don't want user to receive more than one email a day.

My plan is to store this information on a dedicated column `last_sent_at` on table users, and send email only if condition `DateTime.current - last_sent_at > 7.days` is `true`.

EDIT: I should have read last sentence of previous answer... Exactly what I just described... Sorry!